# CENTER_CROP does not maintain image ratio

Tags: android, imageview, crop

By reading the Android doc, I expect a picture with this layout:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/avatar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dip"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

to fill the layout (height of 150 dip is the only condition) without any distorsion:

> CENTER_CROP   Scale the image **uniformly** (maintain the image's aspect
>   ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be
>   equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>   padding).

That works pretty well on phones:

[image]

But on tablet the image is totally distorted:

[image]

How is that possible to say: "please do not stretch horizontally"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're specifying the image as a background rather than as a source. The images look stretched on the phone as well, and CenterCrop should work fine.

Try using the setImageBitmap or the "src" attribute and let me know if it works.